# Python regular expression sub pattern with format string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple output:

```
def main(): 
    output = ['Sum is 60', \
              'Sum is 30','range pattern is normal', 'area is 3', \
              'Sum is 20', 'range pattern is stub', 'area is 1' \
              'Sum is 50']
    cmdOut = '\n'.join(output)
    rangePattern = "range pattern is (?P<rP>(normal|stub))\s*" \
                   "area is (?P<id>[0-9]+)"
    areaPattern = "Sum is (?P<num>[0-9]+)\s*" \
           "(?P<range>(%s)+)?" % (rangePattern)
    patt = "(?P<area>(%s)+)" % (areaPattern)
    for m in re.finditer( patt, cmdOut ):
      print m.group( 'area' )
      print '-'
```

and I want to group each occurrence of sum and range pattern in one group (area). This is my desired output

```
Sum is 60
-
Sum is 30
range pattern is normal
-
Sum is 20
range pattern is stub
-
Sum is 50
```

However, this is what I got:

```
Sum is 60
Sum is 30
range pattern is normal
-
Sum is 20
range pattern is stub
-
Sum is 50
```

I wonder why it does not separate the first and second group although it successfully separates the 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the string formatting at all; it just doesn't help the readability of your pattern.

The problem is your quantifiers.  The complete pattern you have is this:

> (?P(Sum is (?P[0-9]+)\s*(?P(range pattern is (?P(normal|stub))\s*area is (?P[0-9]+))+)?)+)

If I rewrite it for clarity (not for actual functionality) it would look like this:

```
(?P<area>(sum\s(range)?)+)
```

When your pattern matches, the whole "range" part is optional, and the whole thing can be repeated.  So on your first set of input it matches the "Sum ... 60" part, matches the newline, then repeats with the "Sum ... 30\nrange ..." part.

Perhaps you don't want the one-or-more repetition in your group?  Changing that makes your example work for me.  (note that the first match will contain a newline at the end; you may want to remove that before printing it)